# Disable javascript validation using mechanize in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I'm scrapping a website using Mechanize gem, the website has got a form which uses some javascript code for some validation. How do I bypass that?
On form submission, the website redirects to the same form page.

Comment: There was no way to solve this which I could find. I used phantomJS with selenium for scrapping.